# Google Calendar "GDataEntryCalendar" TimeZone Setting

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to Add Google Calender with TimeZone Setting.
Language is objective-c and using gdata-objectivec-client.
Adding Calender without TimeZone Setting is OK, 
but when I add following code,app caught exception,
and message is

'GDataTimeZoneProperty setting undeclared attribute: value'

Does anyone know How to add TimeZone Setting?

```
GDataTimeZoneProperty *timezone = [GDataTimeZoneProperty alloc];
[timezone setDateTimeValue:[GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:
                        [NSDate date] timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]];
[timezone setStringValue:@"Asia/Tokyo" forAttribute:@"Time"];
[newEntry setTimeZoneName:timezone];
```